24.04 - Erratic window sizing actions or mouse movement
Lately I started observing some strange behavior on my Dell XPS 13 9370. As for now it seems to be related to touchpad or touch screen IMHO. It looks like out of the sudden pointer starts clicking on top bar, it fires gnome window resize, so window changes size, colored new window position rectangles appear, sometimes it switches current window (possibly that top window get resized, window below it gets randomly clicked and gets to top of stack, then it clicks back on top bar and starts resizing that window).
Sometimes I'm able to recover with keyboard shortcuts (Super+cursors) to place window at desired location and then Esc to exit (don't know how its properly called) "window placement mode".
It started to appear more frequent in last two weeks, and now it makes my laptop almost useless. During editing of this post it occurred three times. And fourth time it locked my keyboard typing so I had to publish incomplete post and continue editing from my stationary...
I do relate this issue to specific hardware on this laptop rather then distribution itself as on my stationary which also has 24.04 no such things happen.
Anyone has any clues what to look for?
Right now I'm trying to disable pointer devices with xinput disable and I'll see what it does.

These might help https://askubuntu.com/search?q=mouse+clicks+by+itself

It seems that as for now disabling touch screen with xinput solved this problem
